# Como contar filas de una tabla pero dentro de un input con javascript y php

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me permite contar la cantidad de filas pero me habilita ese conteo por medio de un alert, como podria hacer para que me de el mismo resultado pero en un input='text'?

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTableId");
var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
alert(tbody.rows.length);


<table id="myTableId">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

El código funciona muy bien solo que estoy realizando la impresión del total de filas en un alert, pero no se como hacerlo en un input text.

Saludos, cualquier ayuda me seria de gran utilidad muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el campo y asigna el valor en lugar de mostrarlo con *alert*

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTableId");
var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
// En lugar de alert, actualiza el valor del campo
document.querySelector('#filas').value = tbody.rows.length;
```

```html
<table id="myTableId">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
        <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
        <tr><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
        <tr><td>g</td><td>h</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total de filas: <input type="number" id="filas" value="0" size="3" disabled></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```